# string line breaks causing error

Tags: java, android

We can surely, define string in Strings.xml & call - in that case the line break is not an issue.

But suppose I want to put it in my java page -- if I put it as follows - it will bring error

```
String strJson="
      {
         \"Employee\" :[
         {
            \"id\":\"01\",
            \"name\":\"Gopal Varma\",
            \"salary\":\"500000\"
         },
         {
            \"id\":\"02\",
            \"name\":\"Sairamkrishna\",
            \"salary\":\"500000\"
         },
         {
            \"id\":\"03\",
            \"name\":\"Sathish kallakuri\",
            \"salary\":\"600000\"
         }
         ] 
      }";
```

I can fix the error by making it in a single line

```
String strJson=" { \"Employee\" :[ { \"id\":\"01\",\"name\":\"Gopal Varma\",\"salary\":\"500000\"},{\"id\":\"02\",\"name\":\"Sairamkrishna\",\"salary\":\"500000\"}, { \"id\":\"03\", \"name\":\"Sathish kallakuri\", \"salary\":\"600000\" } ] }";
```

But I want to know, instead is there any escape char or something to fix the error.

Comment: Using `''` single inverted comma you can fix it..

Comment: What means "put it in my java page"

Comment: If you write your JSON in a multiline like this, you need to concatane each line (One string is on one line). You can't write one String on multiple line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java String literals cannot span multiple lines, but you can do this.

```
String strJson = "{\n" +
                 "  \"Employee\" :[\n" +
                 "    {\n" +
                 "      \"id\":\"01\",\n" +
                 "      \"name\":\"Gopal Varma\",\n" +
                 "      \"salary\":\"500000\"\n" +
                 "    }\n" +
                 "  ]\n" +
                 "}";
```

Comment: Yes, splitting lines & concatenating with + symbol is the only way... \n is required only if you really want to keep that formatting , otherwise leave it .  Here being a json string I don't need any formatting - what I wanted was better readability only

Comment: And you get the benefit that the compiler concatenates the strings when it's building, as all the strings are known at build time.

Comment: PLEASE NOTE --------  It's always better to define in Strings.xml. The problem with the string concatenation approach is -- it's resource intense -- better NOT to use it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the strings properly,

Try this,

```
String strJson = "{" +
        "\"Employee\": [{" +
            "\"id\": \"01\"," +
            "\"name\": \"Gopal Varma\"," +
            "\"salary\": \"500000\"" +
        "}, {" +
            "\"id\": \"02\"," +
            "\"name\": \"Sairamkrishna\"," +
            "\"salary\": \"500000\"" +
        "}, {" +
            "\"id\": \"03\"," +
            "\"name\": \"Sathish kallakuri\"," +
            "\"salary\": \"600000\"" +
        "}]" +
        "}";
```